# PHP - Access to brothers child class from child class

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I've this php code for you:

```
<?php
    class A{
        public function __construct(){
            $var1=$this->B1();
            $var2=$this->C1();
            echo 'var1: '.$var1.'<br>var2: '.$var2;
        }
    }
    class B extends A{
        protected function B1(){
            return 'b1';
        }
    }
    class C extends A{
        protected function C1(){
            return 'c1';
        }
    }
    new C();
?>
```

Obviously if I change at line 4:

```
$var1=$this->B1();
```

with

```
$var1=$this->C1();
```

I obtain this result:

```
var1: c1
var2: c1
```

But I wanna access to B1() from C and obtain this result:

```
var1: b1
var2: c1
```

And solve this error:
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method C::B1() in file.php on line 4".

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a behavior of different class you should extend from that class. So `C` will have `C1()` and `B1()` both.

But again you want behavior of `C` in `B`. So `B` should contain both `C1` and `B1`.  The resultant classes will have both `C1()` and `B1().

Now you should generalize them. Move them to parent class `A`.

```
   class A{
        public function __construct(){
            $var1=$this->B1();
            $var2=$this->C1();
            echo 'var1: '.$var1.'<br>var2: '.$var2;
        }
        protected function B1(){
            return 'b1';
        }
        protected function C1(){
            return 'c1';
        }
    }

    class B extends A{}
    class C extends A{}

    new C();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class C {
    protected function C1()
    {
        return 'c1';
    }
}

class B extends C 
{
    protected function B1()
    {
        return 'b1';
    }
}

class A extends B 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $var1=$this->B1();
        $var2=$this->C1();
        echo 'var1: '.$var1.'<br>var2: '.$var2;
    }
}

new A;

?>
```